# Как преобразовать массив из A и B элементов, чтобы они чередовались

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм

Необходимо за минимальное количество ходов преобразовать массив состоящий из букв A и B, в массив где они чередуются (нет подряд букв A или B). Ходом считается изменение буквы A на B или наоборот.
Например этот массив:
L = [a, b, b, a, a, a, a, b, a]
В этот массив:
L = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a]
Это заняло 3 хода.

Comment: Не чеши! Например этот массив: L = [a, b, b, a, a, a, a, b, a] В этот массив: L = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a] Это заняло 3 хода.

Comment: Нет попытки самостоятельного решения задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В результате преобразований может получиться только два возможных массива, не так ли? Остаётся проверить количество несоответствий в исходном массиве с обоими вариантами, и выбрать наименьшее.

Comment: Да, спасибо) Об этом я не подумал.